# pandas data.describe() will not print unless it is last entry?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have some clarification here and tried to look around but not able to find out definitively if it is the reason.

stats_df seem to only print if it is the last thing ran. does describe(data.describe()) always have to run last?

i am doing this on jupyter notebook

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

stats_df = data.describe()

stats_df.loc['range'] = stats_df.loc['max'] - stats_df.loc['min']

//will not print
stats_df


out_fields = ['mean','25%','50%', '75%', 'range']
stats_df = stats_df.loc[out_fields]

stats_df.rename({'50%':'median'}, inplace=True)

//will print
stats_df
```

Comment: Are you in a notebook? Wrap it in print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jupyter-notebook, you'll see the output of the last statement if it's not `None` as the result of a cell calculation. It is stored in the dictionary `Out`, so you can reuse it. But it's not printing in its pure meaning. You can suppress this with a semicolon `;` at the very end of your code in a cell. This is good to avoid saving data in `Out` and further troubles when removing them. To print something below the current cell, use `display`, `print`, `pprint` or other similar function.

Some methods in *numpy*, *pandas*, *etc.* display information on a standard output, e.g. `numpy.info` and `pandas.DataFrame.info`. Others return descriptive info *without* printing, e.g. `pd.DataFrame.describe` returns info as a data frame but it *doesn't* print anything. So you have to use some other function to print its output on a display. In your case, I would use `display(stats_df)`.